# Progress bar not updating in iOS swift using SSZipArchive

Tags: ios, swift, progress

I have the following code

```
        SSZipArchive.createZipFile(atPath: zipPath, withFilesAtPaths: testPaths as! [String], withPassword: password, progressHandler: { (entryNumber, total) -> Void in
            let progress = Float(entryNumber + 1) / Float(total)
            print("Zipping file \(entryNumber + 1) of \(total): \(progress * 100)%")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(progress)
                myProgressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
            }
        })
        }
```

I tried moving the code to a background process in case the thread was blocked but that didn't work either.  It executes the print("Zipping.....)" but doesn't update the progress bar nor print the progress.  Any ideas?

I did try moving the command do a background thread but that didn't solve it.

Comment: What is myProgressView, how is it connected to the code you show ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.